# Laravel só informa data atual

Tags: php, laravel, doctrine

Olá, estou informando no *construct* da minha entidade a data da seguinte maneira:

**Entity**:

```
public function __construct($fornecedor, $emissao, $vencimento)
{
    $this->fornecedor = $fornecedor;
    $this->emissao = new \DateTime();
    $this->vencimento = new \DateTime();
}
```

**Form**:

```
{!! Form::open(['url'=>'contas/salvar']) !!}

    {!! Form::label('fornecedor','Fornecedor') !!}
    {!! Form::input('number','fornecedor', null, ['class' => 'form-control','placeholder'=>'Fornecedor']) !!}<br />

    {!! Form::label('emissao','Data de Emissão') !!}
    {!! Form::input('date','emissao', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}<br />

    {!! Form::label('vencimento','Data de Vencimento') !!}
    {!! Form::input('date','vencimento', null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}<br />

    {!! Form::submit('Salvar',['class'=>'btn btn-primary']) !!}

{!! Form::close() !!}
```

**Controller**:

```
public function salvar(Request $request, EM $em)
{
    $Controle = new Controle(
        $request->get('fornecedor'),
        $request->get('emissao'),
        $request->get("vencimento")
    );

    $em->persist($Controle );
    $em->flush();

    return redirect('controle');
}
```

Porém se eu informo qualquer data no meu **Form** ele ignora e registra a data atual. Já tentei colocar dentro da construct `$this->emissao = date_create(date('Y m d'));` mas dá no mesmo. Eu só quero informar dia mês e ano.

**EDIÇÃO**:

Coloquei um `$request->all()` e um `Print_r`, me retornou o seguinte:

```
ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\Controle Object(

[fornecedor:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\Controle:private] => Array
    (
        [_token] => IP5GwnGzUJW6TNsFeIyubFCNfKK7xoKhvgJuoIt1
        [fornecedor] => 1
        [emissao] => 2017-05-06
        [vencimento] => 2017-04-26
    )

[emissao:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\Controle:private] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-04-20 14:47:27
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )

[vencimento:ModuloFinanceiro\Entities\Controle:private] => DateTime Object
    (
        [date] => 2017-04-20 14:47:27
        [timezone_type] => 3
        [timezone] => UTC
    )
)
1
```

Ele esta sob escrevendo?

Comment: Você precisa formatar a `data` enviada pelo formulario e depoisar usar esta string para instanciar a classe `DateTime` dentro da função `saĺvar`

Comment: @RafaelAcioly Poderia me dar um exemplo? Altero a _construct_ para `$this->emissao = date_create(date('Y m d'));` e realizo qual alteração na função?

Comment: faz um `$request->all()` edita e coloca na pergunta? muito estranho o que você está relatando...

Comment: @VirgilioNovic editei e coloquei o retorno. Tive que colocar um $request para emissao e vencimento também, se não, não dava certo...

Comment: Parece que ele está sobreescrevendo @FelipeNunes  ....

Comment: Eu não sei como é feito isso no Doctrine porque eu uso o Eloquent mesmo no Laravel mas, tem algum coisa realcionada a essa linha: `$Controle = new Controle(` e porque não trabalhar com `Eloquent`?

Comment: @VirgilioNovic Eu uso chave composta em meu banco... Assim que eu achar alguma solução, eu posto a resposta.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Resolução**:

Faltou passar como parâmetro `$emissao` e `$vencimento` dentro de `new \DateTime();`

```
public function __construct($fornecedor, $emissao, $vencimento)
{
    $this->fornecedor = $fornecedor;
    $this->emissao = new \DateTime($emissao);
    $this->vencimento = new \DateTime($vencimento);
}
```

Resultado Positivo.